# Check if a user has one of x roles, then remove that role from them

Tags: javascript, discord, roles

I'm trying to build a function that will allow me to check all the members in my Discord server to see if they are in one of a certain set of roles, then remove that role from them.

```
        function StripRoles(){ //will get the players who still have roles assigned to them, and remove those roles
        const RolesArray = ['737531569165565982','737533396422754355','737533710798290974','737532883539066971','737533050925350932','737533864544567296','737534067188301854']; //here's the list of roles
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < RolesArray.length; i++) { //loop that checks each of the roles in RolesArray
            message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => { //for each member of the server
                if (member.roles.has(RolesArray[i])){ //if they have the role currently being checked
                    member.roles.remove(i).catch(console.error); //then remove it from them
                }
           })
        }
    }
```

When I run it, it returns the error:

```
TypeError: member.roles.has is not a function
```

Any help would be appreciated!

edit: added more tags for my own personal newbie-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.includes`:

```
if (member.roles.includes(RolesArray[i])){
```

EDIT:  To help debug, can you do:

```
for (i = 0; i < RolesArray.length; i++) { //loop that checks each of the roles in RolesArray
    message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => { //for each member of the server
        console.log({
            roles: member.roles,
            type: typeof member.roles,
            array: Array.isArray(member.roles)
        });
    })
}
```

and tell me what it logs?

Ok, looking at [discords docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache), I *think* you just need to do:

```
if (member.roles.cache.has(RolesArray[i])){
```

Comment: This just changed the TypeError to 'member.roles.includes is not a function' instead.

Comment: lol then you need to tell us what `member.roles` is, we're all assuming it's an array

Comment: keeping in mind that I'm a total newbie who barely knows what he's doing... to my best knowledge... that portion should be retrieving the list of roles that member has on the discord server. I do not know if this list is an array or something else...

Comment: type came up 'object', array came up false... roles came up with a bunch of info:

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/HG01gqes)_italic_**bold**'code'

Comment: I tried adding cache, the TypeError now reads: "TypeError: [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not an Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes."

Comment: nvm, I spotted the problem for the invalid type - in the remove function I only did i instead of RolesArray[i], thanks a ton for the help! =D

Answer (score 0):

Use `includes` instead of `has`, if `member.roles` is a list.